# Code Generation using T4 Templates

Tags: c#, .net, code-generation, t4

I am using [DataTables](https://datatables.net/) with jquery AJAX and Entity Framework . I return EntityFramework object from a webmethod which serializes it to json . I have lot of tables for which I need to generate CRUD pages , so in backend page there will be CRUD webmethods . I was doing that previously with dynamic data . Is there any way do generate those pages using T4 Templates ?  I dont have exact code at the moment but end result will be something like this

http://editor.datatables.net/release/DataTables/extras/Editor/examples/envelope_inline.html

Here is some example Code in .aspx.cs which returns json

```
    [WebMethod]
    public string GetCustomers(int page)
    {
       return db.Customers.Skip(page*100).Take(100);
    }

   [WebMethod]
    public string DeleteCustomer(int id)
    {
        // ...
    }
```

On .aspx page

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var oTable = $('#example').dataTable( {
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "scripts/server_processing.aspx"            
        }
    } );
} );
```

Comment: sure there is, sample code would make it easier to demonstrate. are you trying to do razor or regular aspx? mvc or web forms?

Comment: With MVC there are built in templates to generate CRUD based on Entity Framework.  What are you using and what have you tried so far?

Comment: @Maslow  I included code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can do it like this:

```
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="false" language="C#" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ output extension="aspx.cs" #>
<# var crudObject= "Customer";
var plural = crudObject+"s"; #>

[WebMethod]
public string Get<#=plural#>(int page)
{
   return db.<#=plural#>.Skip(page*100).Take(100);
}

[WebMethod]
public string Delete<#=crudObject#>(int id)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I see that you have hardcoded crudObject . I want to generate that dynamically . Also If its possible I want to identify primary key from entity framework object and create method so that I can delete based on that primary key column name .

Comment: sure but that seems to me that you are asking WAY to much in a single question.

Comment: @Maslow Just show him how that can be parameterized.  You don't have to give him the whole Bible, just a couple of chapters.

Comment: @RobertHarvey what do you mean?